# Is there a sharp phase change on circuit error rate near the error correction threshold?

Tags: computational-complexity

(I asked this question [on cstheory here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/54028/is-there-a-sharp-phase-change-on-error-rate-near-the-error-correction-threshold), but it received no attention for four days.  Hopefully it is okay to move it to mathoverflow.)

My rough intuition is that if we want to efficiently compute using noisy gates, the probability of success will exhibit threshold behavior as we cross the error correction threshold.  Here is an attempt at formalizing this intuition.  The setting is different from the usual classical/quantum threshold theorems, as the circuit sizes are fixed and the probability is varying.

Let $d$ be the number of Boolean inputs, $n \gg d$ be the size of circuit we want to simulate, and $m > n$ the number of gates we have available.  Assume we have some complete family of Boolean gates with error probability $p \ll 1$, where $p$ will vary.  Let $F_{p,k}$ be the set of distributions on Boolean functions realizable with error $p$, size $k$ circuits.  Define the minimax success probability

$$q_{p,n,m} = \min_{f \in F_{0,n}} \max_{g \in F_{p,m}} \min_{x \in \{0,1\}^d} \Pr(f(x) = g(x))$$

That is, our adversary picks a size $n$ deterministic circuit to simulate, we pick a size $m$ noisy circuit to approximate it, and our adversary chooses an input.

For fixed $n, m$, what does the function $q_{p,n,m}$ look like?  Does it have sharp threshold behavior?  I primarily care about classical circuits, but am also interested if there are results for quantum circuits.

Comment: Dos your use of $m \gg n$ mean $n=o(m)$?

Comment: No, I was being imprecise there, since linear growth would be more typical (enough to capture good error correction circuits).  I changed it to $m > n$.

Comment: Hmmm... Let me try to understand your error correction a bit better. Suppose that the function is just the AND operation on all variables. What error correcting circuit can you offer that makes the final error probability substantially less than $1-(1-p)^n$?

Comment: If $m = cn + O(1)$, one simple thing to do is have $c$ of those and circuits, then take majority vote using an $O(1)$-size circuit.  This will have substantially lower probability of error.

Comment: It looks to me (correct me if i'm wrong) that this will work only in the not so interesting case $p<\frac 1n$. That range can be easily enhanced for *any* circuit in the way you proposed. But what would you suggest for $p$ substantially greater than $1/n$?

Comment: The threshold theorem says that if $p < p_{\textrm{th}}$, we can simulate any circuit (including the and circuit) with error probability $q$ using $m = n \log^a (n/q)$ for some constant $a$.  Inverting this, we get $q = n / \exp (m / n)^{1/a}$.  This can be made very small if $m$ is large enough, even if $p = \Theta(1)$.

Comment: And what is $p_{th}$? Is it some absolute constant?

Comment: Yes, $p_{th}$ is an absolute constant.  Here's a page about the quantum version, but I believe the statement is the same classically: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_theorem.

Comment: I don't believe you. Take AND on just two variables with input 1,1 and create any circuit whatsoever of any complexity you want out of gates that give a wrong answer with probability $p<\frac 12$ each. Consider the last gate in that circuit (the one whose output is the final output). No matter what its inputs are, it outputs $0$ with probability at least $p$. So, no improvement over the single gate AND is possible. What don't I understand here?

Comment: @fedja from what I understand it can't be made arbitrarily small, but a constant times the error probability, for arbitrarily big circuits. See von Neumann's "Probabilistic Logics and the Synthesis of Reliable Organisms From Unreliable Components"

Comment: @fedja You’re right of course, and indeed I think the Wikipedia statement of the theorem is wrong.  But as Command Master says one can prevent the error from growing very much, even for very large $n$.